# Agora: ReactNative is not rendering showing the remote user video in the video call

Tags: android, react-native, agora.io

I am building a Group Video chat application using ReactNative. For the video call, I am using Agora for ReactNative, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-agora. But it is showing black block for remote user video.

This is my code.

```
const agoraAppId = "xxx";
const channelName = "myChannel";
const cerfificateKey = "xxxxx";
const token = "xxxxx";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, PermissionsAndroid, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import RtcEngine, {RtcLocalView, RtcRemoteView, VideoRenderMode} from 'react-native-agora'

const dimensions = {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
}

//https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_react_native?platform=React%20Native
//TODO: pass the id from the previous screen
const AgoraVideoCall = (props) => {
    let engine = null;
    const userId = props.route.params.userId;
    const [ initialised, setInitialised ] = useState(false);
    const [ joinedChannel, setJoinedChannel ] = useState(false);
    const [ engineInitialised, setEngineInitialised ] = useState(false);
    const [ userIds, setUserIds ] = useState([ ]);

    const requestCameraAndAudioPermission = async () => {
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO
            ])

            if (
                granted['android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
                && granted['android.permission.CAMERA'] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
            ) {
                console.log('You can use the cameras & mic')
            } else {
                console.log('Permission denied')
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    const startCall = async () => {
        try {
            if (engine == null) {
                await initialiseEngine()
            }
            await engine.joinChannel(token, channelName, null, userId)
            console.log("StartCall is run")
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("StartCall throws error")
            console.log(engine)
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    const initialiseEngine = async () => {
        try {
            engine = await RtcEngine.create(agoraAppId);
            console.log("Engine initiaised");
            setEngineInitialised(true)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Unable to initialise engine");
            console.log(err);
            setEngineInitialised(false)
        }
    }

    const setUpMeeting = async () => {
        await engine.enableVideo();

        engine.addListener("UserJoined", (uid, elapsed) => {
            console.log(`User has joined, ${uid}`);
            if (uid != userId && userIds.filter(id => id == uid).length < 1) {
                let tempUserIds = [ ...userIds ]
                tempUserIds.push(uid);

                setUserIds(tempUserIds);
                console.log(`User ids have been updated`);
            }
        })

        engine.addListener("UserOffline", (uid, reason) => {
            console.log("User has gone offline");
        })

        engine.addListener("JoinChannelSuccess", (channel, uid, elapsed) => {
            console.log(`Successfully joined the channel, ${channel}, ${uid}`);
            setJoinedChannel(true);
        })

        setInitialised(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        requestCameraAndAudioPermission()
            .then(() => {
                initialiseEngine()
                    .then(result => {
                        setUpMeeting()
                    })
            })
    }, [ ])

    const renderVideos = () => {
        if (! joinedChannel) {
            return null
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.fullView}>
                <RtcLocalView.SurfaceView
                    style={styles.max}
                    channelId={channelName}
                    renderMode={VideoRenderMode.Hidden} />
                {renderRemoteVideos()}
            </View>
        )
    }

    const renderRemoteVideos = () => {
        if (userIds.length < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <ScrollView
            style={styles.remoteContainer}
            contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 2.5}}
            horizontal={true}
            >
                {userIds.map((id, index) => {
                    return (
                        <RtcRemoteView.SurfaceView
                            key={index}
                            style={styles.remote}
                            channelId={channelName}
                            renderMode={VideoRenderMode.Hidden}
                            uid={id}
                            zOrderMediaOverlay={true}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }

    const renderStartCallButton = () => {
        if (joinedChannel) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.actionButton}>
                <Button
                    title={"Start Call"}
                    onPress={() => {
                        startCall()
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

    const leaveChannel = async () => {
        try {
            if (engine ==null) {
                await initialiseEngine()
            }

            await engine.leaveChannel()

            setJoinedChannel(false)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Unable to leave the channel")
            console.log(engine)
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    const renderLeaveChannelButton = () => {
        if (! joinedChannel) {
            return null
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.actionButton}>
                <Button
                    title={"Leave Channel"}
                    onPress={() => {
                        leaveChannel()
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

    const renderContent = () => {
        if (!engineInitialised) {
            return <Text>Initializing the Agora engine</Text>
        }

        if (! initialised) {
            return <Text>Initializing the meeting</Text>
        }

        if (joinedChannel) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.max}>
                    <View style={styles.actionButtonsContainer}>
                        {renderLeaveChannelButton()}
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.max}>
                        {renderVideos()}
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <View style={styles.actionButtonsContainer}>
                    {renderStartCallButton()}
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView>
                {renderContent()}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        flex: 1
    },
    actionButtonsContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row"
    },
    actionButton: {
        padding: 10
    },
    max: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    buttonHolder: {
        height: 100,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    },
    button: {
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#0093E9',
        borderRadius: 25,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: '#fff',
    },
    fullView: {
        width: dimensions.width,
        height: dimensions.height - 100,
    },
    remoteContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 150,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 5
    },
    remote: {
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        marginHorizontal: 2.5
    },
    noUserText: {
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        color: '#0093E9',
    },
})

export default AgoraVideoCall;
```

When the remote video view is rendered, it is rendering the back rectangular block as follow.

[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you share your console log? I'd say double check your remote UIDs that are being passed to the remoteView if they're correct.

Comment: Hi, I found the issue. The uid is new each time the user joins. But when the user leaves and join again with the new id and the token, the previous sessions stay there and those blocks remained.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the remote userIds state when you unmount the component.